# What does the : mean after a value in Scala?

Tags: scala

I just started learning Scala, and I've noticed that `:` is used in many places. Most of the time, the `:` usage makes sense, e.g. after parameter names or method declarations. The following usage confuses me, however:

```
val a = Seq[String]("a", "b")
a :+ "c"
```

or

```
def myMethod(varargs: String*) {
  // ...
}
val a = Seq[String]("a", "b", "c")
myMethod(a:_*)
```

What exactly is the `:` doing in these cases? Why can't I call `a._*` directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two usages that you are asking about are two completely different cases.

```
a :+ "c"
```

The `:` doesn't mean anything by itself here; it's part of a method named `:+`, which appends an element to a `Seq`.

```
myMethod(a:_*)
```

Here, you have a method `myMethod` which takes a variable number of arguments. You want to use the `Seq` to fill the arguments; the `: _*` indicates that you want to do that (rather than pass the `Seq` itself as the first argument of the method).

Note that `:` has a special meaning if a method name *ends* with `:` (not if it begins with `:` as in your first example). In that case, the method will be *right-associative*; it means that the method will be called on the thing on the right, with the thing on the left as the argument, rather than the reverse.

Comment: Thanks. How does `: _*` indicate this? If I wanted to implement this functionality myself, how would I do it?

Comment: +1 For noting that any method ending with `+` is right-associative.

Comment: @Max Have a look at [Daily Scala: Varargs](http://daily-scala.blogspot.nl/2009/11/varargs.html) to learn how to make your own method that takes a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It is telling the compiler that you want your sequence to be taken apart and supplied as separate parameters.

```
def myMethod(varargs: String*) = {
  // varargs is a Seq
  val x:Seq[String] = varargs
}

// Calling it is different
myMethod("a", "b")

// To call using a seq, you need to signal the compiler
myMethod(mySeqOfString: _*)

// They choose the `:` because this would be valid too:
myMethod(myString: String)
```

Int the other example you gave `a :+ "c"` the `:` has a different meaning. It's simply part of the method name. They could have named it `append`, but they chose `:+`. The reason is that the `:` in `+:` has a special meaning: `bind to the right`. This allows for `"c" +: a`. So for sake of consistency they probably chose `:+` for append and `+:` for prepend.

Comment: +1 For noting that any method ending with `+` is right associative.

Answer (score 0):

`:+` is a method on `Seq[A]` which appends the given item to the sequence.

In the second example, `myMethod(a : _*)` the `a : _*` is used to pass a sequence as the variable argument list to the `myMethod` function.

Answer (score 0):

The significance of the colon in Scala varies according to context.

As you note, it separates an identifier in a declaration from its type.

It can also appear as part of an operator involving a sequence.

Since an operator in Scala is really just a method, its use here is arbitrary, but you can rely on the convention that the colon is on the side of a binary operator that points to the sequence.

So your example

```
a :+ "c"
```

Appends the string `"c"` to `a` sequence of strings, while

```
"c" +: a
```

Prepends the string to the sequence. (Or, more precisely in the case of an immutable sequence, returns a new sequence resulting from the prepend/append operation. See [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List))

Your final example

```
myMethod(a: _*)
```

(Which I had to look up *thanks for teaching!* see [documentation](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/11/varargs.html)) tells the compiler to expand the sequence as varargs (rather than as a single argument).

Comment: You should probably mention the associativity quirk of `+:`, for completeness.

Comment: A thing to note here, is that `+:` is Seq's equivalent of List's `::`, `+:` is just better since it works on _all_ sequence types, `::` does not